# Occasional CPU/RAM dips - sign of a looming meltdown?

Tags: windows-7, memory, freeze, crash, resource-monitor

I'm running Windows 7 on my laptop. Using Resource Monitor, I've noticed dips in CPU and RAM performance (I don't know if "failure" is the right word for it) where they'll drop all the way to zero. During this time, my PC freezes, then resumes as normal. I'm not doing anything in particular at the time.

This happens once every 2 hours or so. I do put some pretty serious demand on this computer as I do many tasks at once while working/web browsing... I'm beginning to wonder if I'm killing the old coot.

**These are my laptop specs:**

- Windows 7 32-bit (originally Windows XP)
- 3GB RAM (2.75GB usuable)
- 1.60GHz AMD Athlon TF-20 processor
- 139GB HDD

**What could be causing these sudden dropouts?**

Comment: What software/apps are running when this happens? Look to the task manager dialog for this info and try and make note of the various processes that are running to see if there is something that's consuming all your resources during that period.